# Object as fluid

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

[image]Hello Im new to Blender.
I am trying to make a character playing with a glass of wine, so rotating it a bit.
so I need the wine to be fluid. I found just tutorials how to make inflow simulation for
fluid. how do i give an object physics of fluid without inflow simulation..
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just choose geometry instead of Inflow for Flow behaviour.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but there is some problem. i'd appreciate if you could have a look (I added a pic) . @Chris

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works.
I had to hide the wine object so just the domain to be seen.
and resolution high to 128 so the liquid would look good.
[image]